# Terminate client threads no long being used on Java server

Tags: java

So I have the following code which starts a server and allows clients to connect to it, the question I have is two fold, firstly, once a client disconnects, how do I get the server to terminate that thread? Secondly, this code allows multiple connections, but when I connect a second user the server only responds on that socket, no longer the first clients socket.

Any advice?

```
public Server()
{
    try
    {           
        ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(5000); // Creating a server socket and bind it at port 5000
        System.out.println("Server binded at "+((server.getInetAddress()).getLocalHost()).getHostAddress()+":5000");
        System.out.println("The Cash Dispenser application can now connect");

        while(true)
        {               
            socket=server.accept(); // Ready to accept client request
            System.out.println("Client connected with IP " + socket.getInetAddress());

            new ClientThread(socket).start();   // Spawn a new thread for this socket
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        System.err.println("* err"+err);
    }

}

public class ClientThread extends Thread 
{
    protected Socket socket;

    public ClientThread(Socket clientSocket) 
    {
        this.socket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() 
    {   
        try
        {
            out=new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));  // Opening the input stream to read data from client connection 
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return;
        }

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                socket.getInputStream().read(inputArray);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                return;
            }

            if(inputArray != null)
            {
                for(incomingData = 0; incomingData < (inputArray.length - 1); incomingData++)
                {
                    if(inputArray[incomingData] == ETX)
                    {
                        processData(inputArray);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);                   
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e1)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to close the socket and breaking the while loop.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()

The server will open many ports for socket connection but will be listening on port 5000

Comment: I get that, but how do I sense that the client has dropped the connection and I can now break the loop? Because that loop is the one listening for any new connections, so breaking it will ignore further clients from connecting?

Comment: maybe checked for a dropped connection by using isOutputShutdown and then return from your Thread.